# Extraer datos de atributos HTML con Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, vue.js

Estimados estoy desarrollando un componente collapse (acordion), que me va a mostrar datos. Pero necesito hacer que el metodo donde me muestra los datos se ejecute al incio de la aplicacion:

```
mounted:function(){
     // invocar los métodos
     this.idRubro = this.$el.getAttribute('dataid');
      console.log('idrubros '+ this.idRubro);

    },
```

HTML:

```
  <tr v-for="name in pcuentas" :dataid="name['.key']" :id="div1" :key="name['.key']">

      <td >
         {{name.cuenta}} 

        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  @click="showSubRubro(name['.key'])">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
           <ul class='beer-list'  >
            <li 
            v-for="item in beerList" 
            :key="item.id" 
            v-if="name['.key']===item.id">

                {{ item.nombre }}

            </li>
          </ul> 

          <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
          @click="emitIDRubro(name['.key'])"
          data-target="#ModalSubCuenta" 
          data-toggle="modal" 
          >
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
           </a>
      </td>

    </tr>
```

data del componente:

```
props:['dataid'],
  data() {
    return {
      mensaje: "Agregar rubro a plan contable",
      plandcuenta:{
          nombrepcuenta:'',
      },
      idRubro:'',
      dataid:'',
      idrubros:null,
      beerList: [],
      id:'',
      subrubro:[{}],
      //cuentaShow:[],
      //dataRubros:[{}],
     // notesid:[]
    };
  },
```

Metodo que me muestra los datos:

```
   showSubRubro(id){

    var _this = this
    firebase.database().ref('subrubro/' + id).on('value', function(snapshot) {
      _this.beerList = snapshot.val()
      console.log(_this.beerList)
       console.log(_this.dataid)
    })
```

Necesito colocar a `showSubRubro(id)` dentro de mounted pero no estoy logrando poder capturar el `ID` del atributo `dataid`
Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola Nahuel! ¿estás transpilando el código de Vue?

Comment: Hola Matias, te refieres al llamado del atributo? Creo que es la única forma de llamarlo y obtener el dato del mismo.

Comment: No, a si estás transformando el código con la ayuda Webpack/Babel.

Comment: Podrías dejar más claro, ¿cuál es el código que pertenece a la app? y ¿qué código pertenece al componente?

Comment: No es recomendable repetir el nombre de una prop dentro del atributo data, eso pasa con dataid

Comment: WebPack Matias, pero en que te influye para llamar a un atributo? Todo el código es del componente..

Comment: No te influye a la hora de llamar atributos, pero te permite usar Single File Components (archivos .vue).

Comment: Que me recomiendas para usar y obtener el valor del atributo?

Comment: El problema no esta en el props, pero si es verdad no es recomendable.Ahora me estoy rompiendo la cabeza para poder tomar el valor del atribtuo o voy a tener que buscar otra forma de desplegar el collapse ...

Comment: Podrías compartir un jsfiddle o algo por el estilo con tu código actual?